# Android Fails to get location

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get location of the virtual device AVD the problem here that the location return by null , i have added the permission to the app and still failed to get location

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                      int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        Log.i("Location Info","Permission Denied");
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {
        Log.i("Location Info","Location Achieved ");

    } else {

        Log.i("Location Info", "Location Failed");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
      Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
      Log.i("location Info Lat",longitude.toString());
      Log.i("Location Info long",longitude.toString());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

the result is all the time log info :Location Failed , what is the solution in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location is `null` on emulator because it doesen't know your last sent location (fresh start or something else). You need to send your coordinates to emulator. Works better when you test on a real device.

Edit:

Enter coordinates like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6vrO.png).

Comment: Thanks , You really help me a mile :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was as mentioned by @Florescu it starts from unknown state when i give the emulator the dimension for the first time , find out the emulator understand this as a movement but when i run it again it gives me the correct behavior